# Swiftでビューコントローラーの あるCGPointを含むSubviewを取得する方法はありますか？

Tags: swift

Swiftでビューコントローラーの
あるCGPointを含むsubviewsを取得する方法はありますか？

以下のようにfor文で全てのsubviewに対して、`containsPoint`をして、
判定する方法しかないでしょうか？

```
@IBAction func hundleTapGR(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        print("タップ")
        let point = sender.locationInView(self.view)
        let subviews = NSMutableArray()

        for v in self.view.subviews {
            if v.tag == 1 {
                let view = v as! UIView
                if view.layer.containsPoint(point) == true {
                    subviews.addObject(view)
                }
            }
        }
        print(subviews)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、Swift2.0の時代になっても、まだ`NS(Mutable)Array`にしがみつくことは、やめにしましょう。すなおにSwiftの`Array`型を使ってください。

```
func hundleTapGR(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("タップ")
    let point = recognizer.locationInView(self.view)
    let views = self.view.subviews // Subviewsの配列を取得
    // Arrayのメソッド、filterを活用。pointがフレーム内にあるSubviewをフィルタリング。
    let viewsInPoint: [UIView] = views.filter({(subView: UIView) -> Bool in
        return subView.tag == 1 && CGRectContainsPoint(subView.frame, point)
    })
    結果を出力
    for view in viewsInPoint {
        print("x = \(view.center.x), y = \(view.center.y)")
    }
}
```

`Array`のメソッド、`map`、`reduce`、`filter`を使うと、`for`文で何行も書いていたコードが、1行で書けちゃいます。勉強する価値が、おおいにあると思いませんか？

---

「対象のViewが、座標変換（transform）していたらどないすんねん？」という問題が、別回答で提起されていますが、それは、わざわざ`convertPoint()`を使わなくても処理できます。`UIGestureRecognizer`のメソッド`locationInView()`の使いかたを工夫します。

```
func tapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tappedViews = self.view.subviews.filter({(subview: UIView) -> Bool in
        return subview.bounds.contains(recognizer.locationInView(subview))
    })
    print("number = \(tappedViews.count)")
}
```

かえって、簡潔なコードになりましたね。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
確かにSwift勉強中なんです。

NS(Mutable)Arrayを使わず、Arrayを使うと、
参照渡しでなく、値渡しになると聞いたのですが、

変数の値を変更した後に
再度元のArrayに入れ直すという作業が必要になるのではと思っています。
そんなことはないですか？

Comment: @SPEED MANIA それは別トピックになるんで、ここでお答えするのは、どうかなという気がします。`Array`の要素が、参照渡しでなく値渡しという件は、Swift登場時から熱い話題になっているので、新規に質問をお立てになったら、価値の高い回答が多数寄せられそうに思いますよ。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。
また、機会をみて質問させていただきます。

Answer (score 4):

ダイレクトなAPIはありません。

`CALayer` の `containsPoint(_:)` メソッドは、レイヤーの `frame` ではなく `bounds` がそのポイントを含むか否かなので、質問のコードはたぶん正常に動作しません。

Swift では `CGRect` が拡張されていて、`contains(point: CGPoint) -> Bool` を持っていますので、一番手っ取り早いのは:

```
let subviews = view.subviews.filter {
    $0.frame.contains(point)
}
```

なのですが、`frame`はそのviewに`transform`がかかっているときは[無意味な可能性がある](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame)ので:

> If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI * 45 / 180))
view.frame // -> {x -20.711 y -20.711 w 141.421 h 141.421}
view.frame.contains(CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)) // -> true
```

このような場合に正確に調べたい場合は、座標系を変換して `bounds` と比較した方がよいです。

```
let subviews = self.view.subviews.filter {
    $0.bounds.contains(view.convertPoint(point, toView: $0))
}
```

この場合 `$0.layer.containsPoint(view.convertPoint(point, toView: $0))` と同じですが、`UIView` 使っているときには `.layer` は直接触らない方が良いと思っているので、僕は`bounds.contains` を使います。

Answer (score 1):

CGRectContainsPoint(_ rect: CGRect, _ point: CGPoint)かUIView.pointInside(_:withEvent:)を使うと良いと思います。といっても地道に判定するのは変わりないですが。